# How do I get around in Pokemon Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How do I get around in Pokémon Y? I am looking at my map at the beginning of the game, and I'm at Santalune Forest. Is there any way to get across it?

Answer (score 2):

Over the course of the game you will find or receive [5 HMs (Hidden Machines)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/HM#Generation_VI) which hold moves you can teach to some of your Pokémon to help you reach places you can't reach otherwise. The [HM02](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/HM02) ([Fly](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fly_%28move%29)) can help you more easily travel between towns.

Aside from HM Moves, there is also the [bike](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bike) and the [skates](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Skates), all of which will be needed to reach otherwise inaccessible places. The skates in particular are absolutely vital to navigate through [Shalour Gym](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shalour_Gym).